# Bag implementation, adding items to bag without allowing duplicates

Tags: java, duplicates, multiset, bag

I am trying to implement a ADT MarblesBag in java, where element of the bag are marbles and each marble has the two attributes: colour and weight(so each marble is a triple (item-name, colour, weight). I am struggling to implement a method that adds marble to the bag and throws an exception for duplicate marbles. Here is my code,

```
public void add(Item item) {
        Node<Item> previousnode = first;
        first = new Node<Item>();
        first.item = item;
        first.next = previousnode;
        n++;
```

How can I add an exception for duplicate items in the method?

Comment: Use a java set. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html

Answer (score 0):

That would require implementing and calling method that will check if new element already exists in your collection. This method should be probably called in the beginning of `public void add(Item item)` and should iterate over all elements that are currently present. Method signature can be:

```
private void isAlreadyPresent(Item item) throws ItemAlreadyPresentException{
  .. go through all elements and compare with *item*
  .. if match found
  throw new ItemAlreadyPresentException();
  .. if there is no match then finish method
}
```

Then you can use it before actually adding new element:

```
   public void add(Item item) {
         try {
          isAlreadyPresent(item);
         } catch (ItemAlreadyPresentException e) {
           .. do not add element
           return;
         }
         Node<Item> previousnode = first;
         ...
         n++;
    }
}
```

Java already has Collection that doesn't allow duplicate elements - it's called [Set](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html).